German Crime-Thriller with Showdown of Poisoned Schnapps on a Rotating Board
This is a made-for-TV German crime thriller, which I watched on German TV, possibly on one of the public channels, in the early 2000s (before 2008). I believe it was then a recent movie, if it was a re-run it didn't predate the 1990s.  
I think the main protagonist was a retired police inspector (Kommissar) who lived in an apartment building. He starts to suspect that one of his elderly neighbors is a killer. However, he lacks proof and his former colleagues do not believe him.  
It was centered on the old man, who dies in the end. There weren't many other characters, so I doubt it would have been part of a series. Also, I am certain it lasted ~90 minutes. 
My clearest memory is the final showdown. The main character meets with his neighbor and challenges him. The take turns drinking shots from glasses arranged on a board that they rotate after each turn. At least one of the shots is poisoned. I am not sure who - if anyone - survives this stand-off.

And you're 100% sure it was a movie?

@Walt - no. But it was centered on the old man, who dies in the end. There weren't many other characters, so I doubt it would have been part of a series. Also, I am certain it lasted ~90 minutes.
